# Key value pair is arranging the data automatically based on the key

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I hav created a key value pair in angular. The key is the questionId and value is the baseQuestion , baseQuestion value can be null. Now the problem is that after insertion the key value pair is sorting in ascending order of the key. I want to maintain the insertion order. If that is not possible with the current implementation how we can achieve it. My code so far is

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.questions.length;i++){
    let j= this.questions[i]['questionId'];                
    qnKeyValue[j]= (this.questions[i]['baseQuestion'] == undefined ?null : this.questions[i]['baseQuestion']);
}
```

Comment: Is `qnKeyValue` supposed to be an object? Or an array?

Comment: Then you have an object, and the order of keys in an object is arbitrary. You can't (and shouldn't) rely on the order of properties in an object. If something needs to be ordered, use an array.

Comment: @MattBurland  object or array is ok but  it should be able to send as payload of this format  {"questions":{"367":null,"368":null,"369":null,"370","1025":374,"1026":375,"1027":376,"1028":377,"1029":378,"1030":367,"1031":368,"103"}}

Comment: @MattBurland Using array how to make a key value pair like that

Comment: @SenchuThomas You need an array of objects `{"questions": [{"367":null}, {"368":null}, ...]}`. Also your code can be more readable with `qnKeyValue[j] = this.questions[i]['baseQuestion'] || null;`

Comment: @AlekseySolovey but when I follw this code `qnKeyValue[j] = this.questions[i]['baseQuestion'] || null;` also  the values are ordered based on key. I want it in the inserted order

Answer (score 0):

You can use the loadash dictionary for key value pairs in Angular

*

```
import { Dictionary } from 'lodash';
   let dic: Dictionary<number> = {};
   for (let i = 0; i < this.questions.length;i++){
   let j= this.questions[i]['questionId'];      
   dic[j] = (this.questions[i]['baseQuestion'] == undefined ?null : 
   this.questions[i]['baseQuestion']);;
   }
```

But since dictionary is a hash table I don't think we can sort to the insertion order.
For that you will have to use an Ordered Dictionary.

Comment: using dictionary also sort in ascending order of the key

Comment: That's because dictionary is a Hash table.
You can create a ordered hash in Javascript to maintain the insertion order. My other answer will guide you to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Ordered hash in Javascript to maintain the insertion order.

```
function makeOrderedHash() {
    var keys = [];
    var vals = {};
    return {
        push: function(k,v) {
            if (!vals[k]) keys.push(k);
            vals[k] = v;
        },
        insert: function(pos,k,v) {
            if (!vals[k]) {
                keys.splice(pos,0,k);
                vals[k] = v;
            }
        },
        val: function(k) {return vals[k]},
        length: function(){return keys.length},
        keys: function(){return keys},
        values: function(){return vals}
    };
};

var myHash = makeOrderedHash();
```